# Временной сдвиг в поле даты в одном из полей +04:00 вместо +03:00?

Tags: java, jaxb, simpledateformat

Использую SimpleDateFormat для парсинга строки в дату и наоборот. 
У меня есть адаптер, который читает строки входящего xml перед обработкой и преобразует обратно при отправке клиенту

```
public class DateAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, Date> {
    private final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX");

    @Override
    public String marshal(Date v) throws Exception {
        synchronized (dateFormat) {
            return dateFormat.format(v);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Date unmarshal(String v) throws Exception {
        synchronized (dateFormat) {
            return dateFormat.parse(v);
        }
    }
}
```

Но, возникло непредвиденное поведение:

Подаю на вход дату, она возвращается в преобразованном в таймзону формате - с этим ок, например

```
2009-12-31T23:59:59.000Z      -> 2010-01-01T02:59:59.000+03:00
2009-12-31T23:59:59.000+07:00 -> 2009-12-31T19:59:59.000+03:00
```

Но, когда передаю

```
2001-07-04T12:08:56.235+03:00  -> 2001-07-04T13:08:56.235+04:00
```

вернулся сдвиг +04:00, это работает для одного из полей.
Если передавать xml с датами, то в первом встреченном поле будет этот +04:00 сдвиг, в остальных все норм.
Пробовал менять местами элементы xml, проблема та же, то есть нет привязки к полю, есть привязка к первому встреченному элементу, вероятно к инициализации.

Почему?

Comment: Вы на месяц посмотрите. У вас декабрь и июль, джава учитывает переход на летнее и зимнее время.

Comment: @Russtam Спасибо!